# 404 (The specified blob does not exist.)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, http-status-code-404

I have written the code to download and upload the blob to a container.
I am getting this issue.

> Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed. Status: 404 (The specified blob does not exist.) ErrorCode: BlobNotFound Headers: Transfer-Encoding: chunked x-ms-request-id: 36ac3732-c01e-0039-7b0c-d5881a000000 x-ms-client-request-id: 348fe07c-b87e-409d-9075-8fac337b5e12 x-ms-version: 2021-10-04 x-ms-error-code: BlobNotFound Date: Tue, 22 Aug 2023 15:19:10 GMT Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.d__11.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.d__123.MoveNext()Can you help why this issue is arising even if I have handled the check to verify if the blob exists or not?

```
if (container.GetBlockBlobReference(apkBlobPath).Exists())
```

**Note:** Everything is correct including blob name, container name and storage account.

I have checked on internet that there may be an issue with blob name or container name. But, everything is good with my blob name.

Comment: 404 also appears when credentials or SAS are invalid

Answer (score 0):

***I tried the below code to download and upload a blob to a container in Azure storage.***

**Code** :

```cs
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "<connec_string>";
        string containerName = "<container_name>";
        string apkBlobPath = "<sourceblob_name>";
        string destinationBlobName = "<destinationblob_name>"; 

        BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        if (containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(apkBlobPath).Exists())
        {
            BlockBlobClient sourceBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(apkBlobPath);
            BlobDownloadInfo blobDownloadInfo = await sourceBlobClient.DownloadAsync();
            BlockBlobClient destinationBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(destinationBlobName);
            await destinationBlobClient.UploadAsync(blobDownloadInfo.Content);

            Console.WriteLine("Blob download and upload completed successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source blob does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** :

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

The blob was downloaded and uploaded to another blob in the same container in the Azure portal as below.

***Source blob*** :

[image]

***Destination blob*** :

[image]